# How to find the constant value for this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$
\dot{y} = \frac{1}{4}y(1-\frac{1}{20}y), \quad y(0)=1
$$
using separable approach, we get
$$
4\ln\left( \frac{|y|}{|y-20|} \right) = t+C
$$
Is it possible to find the value of $C$? The natural logarithm is undefined at negative values.

Comment: If you put $t=0$ you get $C=4\ln (\frac  1 {19})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your solution is correct or not, substituting the initial condition works like this,
$$
4\ln\left( \frac{|1|}{|1-20|} \right) = 0+C
$$
Maybe you forgot the absolute value $||$ is in operation in the $\log$.